# React Redux filtering lags a step

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React Redux connected component which is filtering a list of plots based on selections from a series of dropdowns.

It is behaving quite strangely-it filters based not on the current but on the previous selection. Meaning, if I have a list of plots and select "region A," it will show me the same, unfiltered list of plots. However, if I then select "region B," it will show me plots belonging to region A. If I then select "region C," it will show me plots belonging to region B.

There is some kind of logical error in my code, but I'm not seeing it. Can anyone spot it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import { Multiselect } from 'react-widgets';
import 'react-widgets/dist/css/react-widgets.css';

const regions = props => {
    if (props.plots) {
        return Array.from([...new Set(props.plots.map(a => a.region))]);
    }
    return [];
};

const growers = props => {
    if (props.plots) {
        return Array.from([...new Set(props.plots.map(a => a.grower))]);
    }
    return [];
};
const varieties = props => {
    if (props.plots) {
        return Array.from([...new Set(props.plots.map(a => a.variety))]);
    }
    return [];
};
const plotNames = props => {
    if (props.plots) {
        return Array.from([...new Set(props.plots.map(a => a.name))]);
    }
    return [];
};

export class PlotFilterSearch extends Component {
    render() {
        const filters = [
            { prop: 'region', filterArray: this.props.regionFilterArray },
            { prop: 'grower', filterArray: this.props.growerFilterArray },
            { prop: 'variety', filterArray: this.props.varietyFilterArray },
            { prop: 'name', filterArray: this.props.plotNameFilterArray }
        ];

        const filterPlots = () => {
            if (this.props.plots) {
                let filteredPlots = [...this.props.plots];
                filters.forEach(filterObj => {
                    filteredPlots = filteredPlots.filter(
                        a =>
                            (filterObj.filterArray || []).length === 0 ||
                            filterObj.filterArray.includes(a[filterObj.prop])
                    );

                    console.log('filtered plots: ', filteredPlots);
                });
                this.props.storeFilteredPlots(filteredPlots);
            }
        };

        return (
            <div className="plotFilterSearch d-flex col flex-column justify-content-around mt-1 mb-1">
                <div className="multiSelectHolder">
                    <Multiselect
                        data={regions(this.props)}
                        caseSensitive={false}
                        minLength={1}
                        filter="contains"
                        placeholder="Regions"
                        onChange={value => {
                            this.props.regionFilter(value);
                            filterPlots();
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="multiSelectHolder">
                    <Multiselect
                        data={growers(this.props)}
                        caseSensitive={false}
                        minLength={1}
                        filter="contains"
                        placeholder="Growers"
                        onChange={value => {
                            this.props.growerFilter(value);
                            filterPlots();
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="multiSelectHolder">
                    <Multiselect
                        data={varieties(this.props)}
                        caseSensitive={false}
                        minLength={1}
                        filter="contains"
                        placeholder="Varieties"
                        onChange={value => {
                            this.props.varietyFilter(value);
                            filterPlots();
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="multiSelectHolder">
                    <Multiselect
                        data={plotNames(this.props)}
                        caseSensitive={false}
                        minLength={1}
                        filter="contains"
                        placeholder="Plots"
                        onChange={value => {
                            this.props.plotFilter(value);
                            filterPlots();
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        plots: state.plots.plots,
        filteredPlots: state.plots.filteredPlots,
        varietyFilterArray: state.plots.varietyFilter,
        regionFilterArray: state.plots.regionFilter,
        growerFilterArray: state.plots.growerFilter,
        plotNameFilterArray: state.plots.plotNameFilter
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(PlotFilterSearch);
```

Comment: Shouldn't your reduce filter the data for you? I am not sure you are doing redux any justice by this complicated filtering, in rendering filtering. Don't forget that `this.props.plotFilter(value)` is an async action, so it won't be through yet when you call `filterPlots()` directly afterwards. Either your plotFilter should just set the filters, and you filter your data just before rendering it, or you create the filtering on the reducer somewhere, but not how you are doing it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are trying to filter immediately after change with the current props, but the props are updating in the parent and you should wait for them to update before you call filter. You could do it by making use of `componentWillReceiveProps` like below

```
export class PlotFilterSearch extends Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(
          this.props.plotNameFilterArray !== nextProps.plotNameFilterArray ||
        this.props.varietyFilterArray !== nextProps.varietyFilterArray ||
        this.props.growerFilterArray !== nextProps.growerFilterArray ||
        this.props.regionFilterArray !== nextProps.regionFilterArray
         ) {
            this.filterPlots(nextProps);
         }
    }


        filterPlots = (props) => {
            const filters = [
              { prop: 'region', filterArray: props.regionFilterArray },
              { prop: 'grower', filterArray: props.growerFilterArray },
              { prop: 'variety', filterArray: props.varietyFilterArray },
              { prop: 'name', filterArray: props.plotNameFilterArray }
          ];
            if (props.plots) {
                let filteredPlots = [...props.plots];
                filters.forEach(filterObj => {
                    filteredPlots = filteredPlots.filter(
                        a =>
                            (filterObj.filterArray || []).length === 0 ||
                            filterObj.filterArray.includes(a[filterObj.prop])
                    );

                    console.log('filtered plots: ', filteredPlots);
                });
                props.storeFilteredPlots(filteredPlots);
            }
        };
    render() {


        return (
            <div className="plotFilterSearch d-flex col flex-column justify-content-around mt-1 mb-1">
                <div className="multiSelectHolder">
                    <Multiselect
                        data={regions(this.props)}
                        caseSensitive={false}
                        minLength={1}
                        filter="contains"
                        placeholder="Regions"
                        onChange={value => {
                            this.props.regionFilter(value);
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="multiSelectHolder">
                    <Multiselect
                        data={growers(this.props)}
                        caseSensitive={false}
                        minLength={1}
                        filter="contains"
                        placeholder="Growers"
                        onChange={value => {
                            this.props.growerFilter(value);
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="multiSelectHolder">
                    <Multiselect
                        data={varieties(this.props)}
                        caseSensitive={false}
                        minLength={1}
                        filter="contains"
                        placeholder="Varieties"
                        onChange={value => {
                            this.props.varietyFilter(value);
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="multiSelectHolder">
                    <Multiselect
                        data={plotNames(this.props)}
                        caseSensitive={false}
                        minLength={1}
                        filter="contains"
                        placeholder="Plots"
                        onChange={value => {
                            this.props.plotFilter(value);
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to say const filterPlots =()...? Leaving this the way it is throws an error: "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: filterPlots is not defined". Adding "const" throws another error-it says "filterPlots" is an unexpected token. Defining the function outside the component and invoking it as a callback creates an infinite loop.

Comment: ohh, sorry, it should be called like this.filterPlots() from componetWillReceiveProps, Updated the answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

You're declaring filterPlots outside both render() and componentWillReceiveProps(). And you're declaring it without "const" or "let". What gives?

Comment: That is a syntax thing, we don't need const or let for writing class methods

Comment: And what did you change in your answer?

Comment: `this.filterPlots(nextProps);` instead of `filterPlots(nextProps);` in componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: That throws it into an infinite loop.

Comment: Ohh, that is because all the conditions in the `componentWillReceiveProps` fail since you are returning a new instance from `growers` and other functions everytime

Comment: OK, fixed it in your code, now it works. Will accept answer as soon as you accept the edits.